# Java Encryption done is not matching with .Net Encryption both encryption are different

Tags: java, c#, .net, encryption

Code is running without any error but not getting encrpted correctly as same as from Java code.

**.Net Code :**

```
public static string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string key)
{
    using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        myRijndael.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(key);
        myRijndael.IV = new byte[16];
        return EncryptStringToBytes(stringToEncrypt, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
    }
}

public static string EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    byte[] encrypted;

    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;
        rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {

                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    if (plainText.Length < 16)
                    {
                        for (int i = plainText.Length; i < 16; i++)
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write((byte)0x0);
                        }
                    }
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                Enc = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
                //encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
    return Enc;
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to post the java code?